# Using a list to centrally manage type mappings?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of type mappings I need to register in an Install method and remove in an Uninstall method. At the moment my code looks like this:

Install:

```
var serviceLocatorConfig = new ServiceLocatorConfig();
serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping<IListItemRepository, ListItemRepository>();
serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();
serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping<IIssueRepository, IssueRepository>();
...
```

Uninstall:

```
var serviceLocatorConfig = new ServiceLocatorConfig();
serviceLocatorConfig.RemoveTypeMapping<IListItemRepository>(null);
serviceLocatorConfig.RemoveTypeMapping<ITaskRepository>(null);
serviceLocatorConfig.RemoveTypeMapping<IIssueRepository>(null);
...
```

and these continue for several more mappings.

The thing I don't like here is as I add a new repository I have to add a new line to both the install method and the uninstall method. What I want is something like this

```
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _typeMappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
                                             {
                                                 {typeof(IListItemRepository), typeof(ListItemRepository)},
                                                 {typeof(ITaskRepository), typeof(TaskRepository)},
                                                 {typeof(IIssueRepository), typeof(IssueRepository)},
                                                 ...
                                             };
```

and then for my install and uninstall methods I could just iterate the collection...

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> mapping in _typeMappings)
{
    serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping<mapping.Key, mapping.Value>();                
}
```

and

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> mapping in _typeMappings)
{
    serviceLocatorConfig.RemoveTypeMapping<mapping.Key>(null);                
}
```

As I add more repositories I would only have the `_typeMappings` collection to update, and not have to worry about updating both methods.

Problem is, the `RegisterTypeMapping` method in the body of the foreach complain that it is expecting either the name of a namespace or type. I also tried

```
serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping<typeof(mapping.Key), typeof(mapping.Value)>();
```

too but it didn't like that either.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] The `RegisterTypeMapping` method signature is defined below

```
public void RegisterTypeMapping<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom, new()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's a compile time error - The type or namespace name 'mapping' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the generic version of `RegisterTypeMapping` where you actually want the normal version:

```
serviceLocatorConfig.RegisterTypeMapping(mapping.Key, mapping.Value);
```

**EDIT:**

If only the generic version is available to you, I think you can construct the appropriate generic method using reflection & `MakeGenericMethod()`
(Totally untested!)

```
serviceLocatorConfig.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterTypeMapping").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { mapping.Key, mapping.Value}).Invoke(serviceLocatorConfig, null);
```

Comment: The method signature of RegisterTypeMapping is public void RegisterTypeMapping<TFrom, TTo>(string key) so your suggested method call is invalid. I'll add this to the original question.

Comment: By templated I think you mean generic, we're not doing C++ anymore :)

Comment: @Mark: I was going off this page which shows two prototypes. One generic that takes actual types, and a standard version that takes Type objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648762.aspx

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Ah ok, unfortunately the service locator I'm using doesn't have that overload defined in it. For reference I'm using the service locator included in SharePoint Guidance. There's some documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648088.aspx